# Темизация полос прокрутки без использования библиотек

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Хочу темизировать стандартные полосы прокрутки на сайте. Пробовал использовать стандартные библиотеки.

---

В интернете то их полно. Но скорее всего они у меня конфликтуют с другими и работать отказываются.

---

Так вот вопрос можно ли полемизировать их без использования библиотек, мне бы достаточно было, наверное, хотя бы class к ним прицепить, да и такой скрипт места меньше займет чем целая библиотека из набора ненужных мне правил.

Comment: В IE6+ были свойства типа [`scrollbar-base-color`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/scrollbar-base-color), но они нестандартные и кроме IE нигде не работают. В большинстве библиотек полосу прокрутки скрывают через `overflow:hidden`, делают вспомогательный блок-ползунок и при взаимодействии с ним смещают зависимый контент. **Без использования библиотек - нет, нельзя** Или пишите свою, либо подберите готовую под себя.

Comment: Какое интересное слово "темизация" ))

Answer (score 2):

Вы вполне можете обойтись использованием CSS. Все библиотеки на JS прячут скролл и в целом по одинаковой формуле расчитывают свой скроллбар уже на основе div блоков и их высот, генерируя свою разметку. Такой вариант на JS имеет право на жизнь, если у вас есть требование точной гарантии кроссбраузерности. Чтобы покрыть просто большее количество браузеров, вы можете обойтись простым CSS, правда поддержка будет только у WebKit и IE, а также в Opera после перехода на WebKit
Для WebKit Браузеров вам помогут свойства

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-resizer
```

Для IE вам помогут стили

```
scrollbar-base-color: 
scrollbar-base-color: 
scrollbar-3dlight-color: 
scrollbar-highlight-color: 
scrollbar-track-color: 
scrollbar-arrow-color
scrollbar-shadow-color: 
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color:
```

А вот с FireFox ничего не получится, только JS. И в целом вы могли бы обойтись одной библиотекой, вопрос конфликтов решается разработчиком всегда.